# exception 'TwitterException' with message 'Bad Request'

Tags: authentication-authorization, social-network

I am trying to setup [twitter](http://drupal.org/project/twitter) module for Drupal 7 on my localhost. I followed the installation instructions as given in [Twitter 7.x installation guide](http://drupal.org/node/1346824). I followed steps until "Add Twitter accounts" when i start getting this error.

```
Could not obtain a valid token from the Twitter API. Please review the configuration.
```

The dblog has the following information:

> exception 'TwitterException' with message 'Bad Request' in
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\sites\all\modules\twitter\twitter.lib.php:142
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\sites\all\modules\twitter\twitter.lib.php(101):
>   Twitter->request('https://api.twi...') #1
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\sites\all\modules\twitter\twitter.lib.php(51):
>   Twitter->auth_request('https://api.twi...', Array) #2
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\sites\all\modules\twitter\twitter.pages.inc(336):
>   Twitter->get_request_token() #3
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\includes\form.inc(1464):
>   twitter_auth_account_form_submit(Array, Array) #4
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\includes\form.inc(860):
>   form_execute_handlers('submit', Array, Array) #5
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\includes\form.inc(374):
>   drupal_process_form('twitter_auth_ac...', Array, Array) #6
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\includes\form.inc(131):
>   drupal_build_form('twitter_auth_ac...', Array) #7
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\sites\all\modules\twitter\twitter.pages.inc(130):
>   drupal_get_form('twitter_auth_ac...') #8 [internal function]:
>   twitter_user_settings() #9
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\includes\menu.inc(517):
>   call_user_func_array('twitter_user_se...', Array) #10
>   C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
>
> ## 11 {main}

I also have oauth module installed as given in the requirements.

Additional info:

- My machine accesses internet via a proxy server and i do have proxy settings given in settings.php file. Not sure why it should cause problems.
- I was able to run twitter API commands using [twitteroauth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) in a standalone application. It was throwing errors before i gave it the proxy settings for curl.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is SSL working on your local install?

Comment: I doubt its working. I do have php_openssl extension enabled. I'll double check that.

Comment: Additionally, the stable version has an issue when trying to authenticate an account. You need to use the dev version in order for that to work (although it doesn't seem that's your current issue).

Comment: @enzipher I followed instructions [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,32986) and now i can access my localhost via https. I'm still getting the same error. Any more pointers?

Comment: Difficult to say what it could be, but I would double check the app setup and the anywhere domains. You might need to have a vhost domain such as 'mysite.local' for the app.

Comment: @enzipher I did try by setting a domain name for local host. Dint help. Although i got my work done by using [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library, i'll try to spend some more time to figure out why twitter module for drupal wouldn't connect on my local computer. Thanks!

Comment: I have not followed the suggestions added to this answer before, so might be redundant.Still, I am able to setup this module successfully on my local.Here is what is I did I created virtual host entry for my drupal installation and added local ip mapping to my a domain name I picked for this installation on my local.But I am not using any proxy settings with connection.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a lot of trouble setting the Twitter module up on my localhost for testing, so I just created a blog post about how to set that up, that includes some tips on doing this with localhost: http://drupalwoo.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/how-to-show-tweets-from-your-twitter-account-on-your-drupal-website/

Here are the couple of things that I think my be relevant for you to check:

1. If you’re testing on localhost, use the following urls for your website and callback URLs (don’t worry, these are just placeholders, and your drupal site will send the correct callback URL when it connects):

   ```
   Website URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/oauth
   Callback URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/oauth
   ```
2. If you’re still getting errors when testing with localhost, make sure the version of the module you’re using has the patch #5 on this issue queue: http://drupal.org/node/1924478#comment-7260928 (if you have an older version of the module, prior to the incorporation of the patch, get the latest stable/dev release that includes it and uninstall and install the module)

Comment: I was logged in to my twitter account in the same browser all the time. Dint help. :(

Comment: Also, did you check that the 'Website' and 'Callback' URLs on the twitter application match what's listed in the settings tab of the Twitter module?  They all have to match...

Comment: yeah.. the callback urls were configured as given in the installation guide..

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?  What website and callback URL are you using in your dev.twitter.com application configuration?  I just realized you're trying to set this up for localhost.

Comment: In any case, I've edited my answer with some additional ideas and what may be a helpful blog post.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey, I did follow the steps that you have mentioned. Those are the same which are detailed in the guide [Twitter 7.x installation steps](http://drupal.org/node/1346824). I haven't yet figured out the problem. Although, i suspect something is wrong with my environment settings rather than drupal code/twitter module configurations, since i was able to invoke Twitter API calls from standalone php code using [twitteroauth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) which required configuration in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

There is some change in twitter api. I was also facing some issue while connecting twitter.  The Patch has been applied by the module maintainer and so either update your module or go through [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1924478) and apply the patch. This patch works fine http://drupal.org/node/1924478#comment-7260928